# Using static ip devices on different network

Tags: networking, subnet, static-ip

This is probably a very easy question but I'm a little confused by sub-nets. I use my machine on on a home and work network.

- The home network is 192.168.0.x
- The work network is 192.168.1.x

On the work network it would be useful to use a static IP e.g. 192.168.1.16.
Can I use a sub-net mask to make this work on a home network, i.e. change it to 255.255.0.0. Is this the right use for a sub-net?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you could change the netmask on one (or both) of the networks to 255.255.0.0 - but you will need to change all the devices in that network to share the new network for things to work correctly [ otherwise some devices would not be able to talk to your computer ]

Comment: I'll give it try tonight but this makes sense.